# Passing an array directly to a function in Shell

Tags: arrays, shell

is it possible to pass an array directly to a function in shell/bash, without saving it first to a variable?

currently example:

```
function checkParameter(){
    param1=("${!1}")
    for a in "${param1[@]}"; do
        echo "${a}"
    done

    param2=("${!2}")
    for b in "${param2[@]}"; do
        echo "${b}"
    done
}

a=( "child 1 from 1" "child 2 from 1" "child 3 from 1" )
b=( "child 1 from 2" "child 2 from 2")
checkParameter a[@] b[@]
```

So can I pass the `( "child 1 from 1" "child 2 from 1" "child 3 from 1" )` and the `( "child 1 from 2" "child 2 from 2")` somehow directly to the function `checkParameter`, without saving it in `a` and `b` first?

greetings and thanks,
christopher2007

Comment: What you are doing here is *indirectly* passing the "name" of the array to the function and then expanding that for its values in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$1" is immutable. That is why your example has to store the value of it in a temporary variable. This holds true for `$@` regardless of whether they are passed as an array or not.

Comment: so is there an workaround? maybe an other value type? ... sry, my english is very bad and so I can not understand the howl message you wrote :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to use an array ?

```
checkparameters() {
    for param in "$@"; do
        echo "$param"
    done
}

checkparameters "a" "b" "c"
```

To answer the question, I don't think that is possible to pass an array as function's args without transformations.

**EDIT**

You could try something like :

```
[ ~]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash 

declare -a a1
a1=("a" "b")

declare -a a2
a2=("c" "d")

checkParameters(){
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo "Content of $i :"
        for j in $(eval "echo \${$(echo $i)[@]}"); do
            echo $j
        done
    done
}

checkParameters "a1" "a2"
[ ~]$ ./test.sh 
Content of a1 :
a
b
Content of a2 :
c
d
```

Comment: yea, because in the original I have to pass two individual arrays with different and dynamic length to the function. I changed my question with a better example for that. sorry for trying to keep the first example so short, that this was impossible to see.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but I have a lot of function calles like this in a if/elif/elif/.../elif/else construction and I can not define new arrays between them. it is something like `if [ checkParameters "a1" "b1" ] ... elif [ checkParameters "a2" "b2" ] ... elif [ checkParameters "a3" "b3" ] ...` and therefor I have to define all this arrays BEFORE the first "if" and to avoid this, I hoped that I could call the function with the arrays directly ...

Comment: The OP's own code using variable indirection `${!…}` via `a[@]` and `b[@]` is both simpler and more robust than your `eval`-based solution, (which also relies on array _variables_, which is the very thing the OP is trying to avoid).
Aside from the risks inherent in `eval`, your solution will break with elements containing embedded whitespace (as used in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you *cannot* pass arrays to Bash scripts or functions *as arrays*:

When you pass an array on the command line, e.g., `"${ary[@]}"`, you're not passing an *array*, but its *elements* as *individual parameters*; the first array element is bound to special parameter `$1`, the second to `$2`, ...

Your solution attempt employs a clever workaround by passing the *name* of array *variables* to the function, where *variable indirection* (`${!...}`) is used to access the array inside the function.<sup>[1]</sup>

By definition, this approach requires the arrays to be stored in *variables* up front.

As for your desire to **do it without storing your arrays in a variable**: You cannot pass array *literals* as arguments in Bash; the conceptual equivalent of that is to **simply pass *individual parameters*.**

The problem with that is that **you won't be able to tell where the elements of one array end and the next one begins**.

You can address that by introducing a *separator* parameter whose sole purpose is to indicate when an array ends.

For instance, if you know that your elements never contain a newline, **you can use `$\n` as the separator:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function checkParameter(){
  local -i arrayNdx=1
  for param; do # Loop over all parameters
    [[ $param == $'\n' ]] && { (( ++arrayNdx )); continue; }
    echo "From array $arrayNdx: [$param]"
  done  
}

# Pass the array elements as individual parameters
# and use $'\n' (a newline) to separate the elements of the 1st
# array from those of the 2nd.
checkParameter "a1-child 1" "a1-child 2" "a1-child 3" $'\n' "a2-child 1" "a2-child 2"
```

---

<sup>[1] Just to show a simplified version of your solution to make the variable-indirection part clearer:</sup>

```
function checkParameter(){
    for a in "${!1}"; do
        echo "${a}"
    done

    for b in "${!2}"; do
        echo "${b}"
    done
}

checkParameter a[@] b[@]
```